# Cannot start network-manager on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: network-manager, 17.10

I cannot start **network-manager** on my Ubuntu 17.10. It gives me the following error.

```
Failed to execute child process “/snap/bin/network-manager.networkmanager”
```

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: hmm how are you trying to start Network Manager? In general, it runs as a service (a background process) and is started on boot. Have you installed it as a snap? If so, why?

Comment: Could you please show what `sudo service network-manager status` in the terminal looks like?